# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error on CLOB variable

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have an AJAX callback that retrieves a CLOB value from a table.

```
DECLARE
    L_CLOB CLOB;
BEGIN
    SELECT LOG 
    INTO L_CLOB 
    FROM TAB1
    WHERE COL1 = apex_application.g_x01;

    htp.p(L_CLOB);
END;
```

However, when the CLOB is too large, it returns

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: None of [the HTP subprograms](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/arpls/HTP.html#GUID-ABA9F627-267D-4CBB-AB86-0B361D6747C1) have CLOB argument, so you're limited to the maximum size of a `varchar2`; if the CLOB is larger than 32k it will give that error. You'll have to decide how you want to handle that - probably by breaking the value up into multiple lines?

Comment: @AlexPoole Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the **APEX_JSON** Package you can return CLOBS. The **htp.p** Package does not support CLOB output, if you want to use that you have to split the CLOB up into smaller Chunks of VARCHAR2.

Using the **APEX_JSON** Package is much more convenient, you can just pass a **CLOB** as a Parameter to the write procedure:

```
apex_json.open_object;  
apex_json.write('mydata', MY_CLOB);  
apex_json.close_object;
```

If you put that into an **AJAX Callback Procedure** on a Page and then use this Javascript to call it:

```
 apex.server.process(
    'MY_AJAX_PROCEDURE',   // Process or AJAX Callback name
    {}, //No Parameters
    {
      success: function (pData) {        
        console.log(pData); //The Data will be logged into the console
      }
    }
  );
```

You will see your CLOB data in the console. You can also do everything else with it.